# Manipulate numpy array following instructions in a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have two equal sized numpy arrays, containing floats in one and smallish integers in the other:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([[0.1, 1.5, 2.4, 0.1], [3.4, 1.9, 8.8, 6.3]])
arr2 = np.array([[1, 2, 1, 5], [3, 3, 4, 5]])
```

as well as a dictionary carrying manipulation-instructions with the `arr2` values as keys:

```
instructions = {1: 'keep as is', 2: 'multiply 2', 3: 'minimum(as-is, 0.1)', 4: 'overwrite 5.0', 5: 'keep as is'}
```

How can I manipulate `arr1` following the instructions in the dict, using the corresponding `arr2` values as the look-up keys? The desired output would be:

```
arr_out = np.array([[0.1, 3.0, 2.4, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 5.0, 6.3]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Create a dict-map for all operation and then use zip to do all operation.

Check out this code:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([[0.1, 1.5, 2.4, 0.1], [3.4, 1.9, 8.8, 6.3]])
arr2 = np.array([[1, 2, 1, 5], [3, 3, 4, 5]])

instructions = {1: 'keep as is', 2: 'multiply 2', 3: 'minimum(as-is, 0.1)', 4: 'overwrite 5.0', 5: 'keep as is'}

dict_ = {
    1: lambda i:i,
    2: lambda i:i*2,
    3: lambda i:i-0.1,
    4: lambda i:5.0,
    5: lambda i:i
}
list_ = np.array([dict_[i] for i in arr2.flatten()])

arr = np.array([])
final = np.array([op(parm) for op, parm in zip(np.array(list_).flatten(), arr1.flatten())]).reshape(2,-1)
print(final)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[[0.1 3.  2.4 0.1]
[3.3 1.8 5.  6.3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define the methods you need then map it in a dictionary. This is just an example that you must adjust for your case.

```
import numpy as np

def multiply_by_2(ary):
  ary *= 2

operations = { 1: multiply_by_2 }

ary = np.array([0, 1, 2])
print(ary) #=> [0 1 2]

operations[1](ary)
print(ary) #=> [0 2 4]
```

Comment: thanks, it hadn't occurred to me to put a function as the dictionary values!